# Cloning a VPS into a local VM?

Tags: vps, vmware-server, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, virtuozzo

I've got a fun challenge for you all.  A company I'm working with is setting up its development/release workflow and environments.  The eventual production environment is a VPS hosted with a popular host running CentOS within a Virtuozzo virtualization environment.

We'd like to install a virtualized instance of the production environment (or something close to it) to each developer's local system.  This will allow each developer to test changes locally on his/her own system without tainting anyone else's system when things go wrong.

Clearly, there are many ways to do this, but I imagine there's a specific approach that is superior.  This is where I need your help.

So far, the best options seem to be as follows.

---

**Export/Back up the Virtuozzo VM.  Download it to a local system and install it into a Virtuozzo Container.**

This is the cleanest/purest solution, but it may not work.  The cloned VM would still have all of the network configuration from the VPS' network, for example.  Would it be hard to write a script to update these (and any other old configuration values) so they are more appropriate for the local VM?

**Deploy the codebase to a similarly configured VM created in an arbitrary virtualization product.**

This approach isn't as clean, but I know it can work (I've done it before).  For example, we could install the same version of CentOS, Apache, MySQL, etc. to a local VMWare VM.  The environment wouldn't be identical to the production environment, but it might be close enough to make this workflow feasible.

**Another option?**

What other options do you think there may be?  Or, is one of these options the best?  I'd love to hear your thoughts! :)

---

Edit:

**Multiple cPanel/user accounts on the production server**

I contacted our VPS' customer support to see if I could obtain access to the Virtuozzo backups; he denied our request but suggested that we might try creating a separate cPanel/user account for each developer.  This would allow the environment to be identical to that of the server, but would be a little more inconvenient since the environment would still be running remotely instead of locally.  Still, a decent option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work perfectly for you ...

On the source VM instance ...

```
sudo su
cd /
tar cvpzf backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

On the target machine (dedicated or VPS)

```
tar xvpfz backup.tgz -C /
```

And make sure any dirs excluded are re-created

```
mkdir proc
mkdir lost+found
mkdir mnt
mkdir sys
```

You could just create a nice Microsoft VirtualPC Linux image and hand it out to everyone

Comment: Have you done this before?  This seems so simple, but sometimes the simplest solutions turn out to be the most reliable/elegant...

Comment: A few times actually. With the exception that we did it with dedicated servers. The only thing you need to bear in mind is the contents of /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/menu.lst - as these will be platform dependant.

Comment: Fascinating.  This is one of those things for which there are MANY solutions, and yours is quite intriguing.  Thanks so much for your response. :)

Comment: The fact you can do it on a running server is the best bit :)

Comment: Just as a follow-up - it has been a few years, and we actually went with the "similarly configured VM" approach described in my question.  I don't recall exactly why we did - I think I might have had a hard time getting the archived files to execute in the VM - you know, different platform and all from the actual server.  Or, maybe I had a hard time creating the archive.  Regardless, it's good to know that this works well on actual dedicated servers!  Thanks again for your answer.